# Getting "User is not authenticated" exception in cognito

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I have registered one user using  AWS Cognito android SDK. I am login with user on one device and I am able to fetch all the attributes of the user.But when I log in with same user on different device it gives me CognitoNotAuthorizedException (user is not authenticated message) and I am not able to fetch the attributes.

I have checked on Cognito user pool and the user has been registered and confirmed also phone number has been verified.Is there any version specification for getUserDetails() method which I  am missing.I also ran signup/login/forgot password functionality on second device and all are working fine except getUserDetail.Below Code I am using for getting user details.

```
private void getDetails() {
      AppHelper.getPool().getUser(mUsername).getDetailsInBackground(detailsHandler);
  }

  GetDetailsHandler detailsHandler = new GetDetailsHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
          AppHelper.setUserDetails(cognitoUserDetails);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
          showDialogMessage(getString(R.string.could_not_fetch_user_data), AppHelper.formatException(exception), true);
      }
  };
```

Comment: Please post the exception.

Comment: @Bansal_sneha Did you got any solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi, I face same issue on last couple of days. If you find any solution, please share with me.

Comment: hi guys, in my case it was some proxy settings were there on device due to which client SDK wasn't able to authenticate the user.